# GOP Reassembly/Display Order

Tags: compression, mpeg

When dealing with MPEG compression, the following group of pictures ((GOP (I-, P- and B-Frames)) is coded and transmitted in the following order:

`I P B B P P B B P B B P P`

The display order, however, is:

`I P P B B P P B B P B B P`

Could somebody kindly explain how this particular order is determined (I know that it's not random, but am unsure what guideline/logic is used when reordering the frames)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your frame sequences aren't quite right:

Display order: `I(1) B(2) B(3) P(4) B(5) B(6) P(7)`

Transmit order: `I(1) P(4) B(2) B(3) P(7) B(5) B(6)`

The short answer for why this is so: Due to the bidirectional nature of B frame prediction the decoder must first process the previous and next reference frames. For example, to decode B(2) the decoder must first have I(1) and P(4).

The easy way (for most sequences) to reorder frames from transmission to display is to look at the temporal_reference in the picture header which gives you the location of the frame in display order.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great, thank you; however, I was given then above example and the answer, but could not determine exactly how a person could look at the out-of-sequence frames and put them in order?  I understand that the frames are transmitted out of sequence and then reordered upon arrival at their destination, but I have no idea how a person could reorder the frames manually.  Can you, perhaps, shed some light on this, too?

Comment: As I said, one easy way would be to look at the temporal_reference value in the picture header. The MPEG2 spec has a more detailed algorithm based on frame type along.

What is it your are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to determine how a person looking at this out-of-sequence GOP on a piece of paper can come to the correct sequence without the use of a computer?

Comment: If the current frame in coded order is a B frame then the output that frame. If the current frame is an I or P frame then output the previous I or P frame if one exists. If no previous I or P frame exists then no frame is output.